# Why is my stream socket only queuing one connection at a time from my browser?

Tags: python, sockets, browser, tcp

I am binding a socket to localhost:8888, in order to make a simple server.
Here is the simple python script that I used to create the server.

```
import os
import socket
import fcntl

tuples = socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 8888, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE | socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG)

res = tuples[0]

af, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr = res
sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)

flags = fcntl.fcntl(sock.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFD)
flags |= fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
fcntl.fcntl(sock.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFD, flags)

sock.setblocking(0)        
sock.bind(sockaddr)
sock.listen(128)
```

1. Now I open this script using an interactive shell.
2. Then I go to my browser, and visit http://localhost:8888, which should queue up a connection to my server.
3. I repeat the last step a few more times,
   each time inside a new tab.

**At this point, I expect to have many connections queued up for my server.**

To check this, I go into my interactive shell and I type:

```
sock.accept()
```

This works on the first try, but **on subsequent tries I get Erno 11 (EAGAIN), which tells me that no other connections are queued up.** However, in my browser, the little "Connecting" spinner is still going on each tab I opened! I have tried this in both Chrome and Firefox.

I my wrote my own client that connects to localhost:8888, and was able to queue up connections with no problems. What is going on here?? Can anyone please check if this experiment can be verified on their own browsers?

For convenience, here is my client:

```
import os
import socket
import fcntl

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 8888))
s.recv(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely an optimisation on the side of your browser, trying to reuse the same connection - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection.

If you want to make sure, sniff the traffic using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), although your localhost based address may require some fancy setup.

Comment: Whoever designed this was living in a state of sin. Why would it make sense to specify a transportation layer parameter inside the application layer (which depends on the transportation layer!)? By the time my message gets to its destination, it is already too late to specify how I want the message to be sent!

Comment: TCP is great, except where it isn't  [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) is supposed to fix those issues, but is not widely available yet.

Comment: To test your hypothesis, I opened up the server and I sent a browser request to localhost:8888. Then I did sock.accept() to create the connection. Before receiving the contents of the request, I sent another browser request to localhost:8888. Then I called connection.recv(), but there was only one GET request inside (instead of two).

Comment: Probably the second one would only be sent if the first is finished. Better solution would have been to create a 2nd connection if the 1st one is delaying...

Comment: @glglgl: Unfortuantely, I cannot change the implementation of my browser to do this.